# BeautifulSoup Exception mid loop scraping HTML file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm trying to scrape a local folder of HTML files for a couple of variables but I'm getting an exception about halfway through the loop. The exception is `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'contents`. It is not actually `.contents` I've looked at the file it gets hung up on and it's structured exactly the same as the other files. If you remove `.contents` then you just raise the same exception but with the `find()` function. Anyone know why this is happening? Again many of the files process without a problem. My code is below:

```
df_list = []
folder = 'rt_html'
for movie_html in os.listdir(folder):
    with open(os.path.join(folder, movie_html)) as file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
        title = soup.find('title').contents[0][:-len(' - Rotten Tomatoes')]
        audience_score = soup.find('div', class_ = 'audience-score meter').find('span').contents[0][:-1]
        num_audience_ratings = soup.find('div', class_ = 'audience-info hidden-xs superPageFontColor')
        num_audience_ratings = num_audience_ratings.find_all('div') [1].contents[2].strip().replace(',', '')
    
    
        # print(num_audience_ratings)
        # break
           
        df_list.append({'title': title,
                        'audience_score': int(audience_score),
                        'number_of_audience_ratings': int(num_audience_ratings)})
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['title', 'audience_score', 'number_of_audience_ratings'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that some of the files do not have the attributes you are looking for.

Eg.

```
 audience_score = soup.find('div', class_ = 'audience-score meter').find('span').contents[0][:-1]
```

If there is no `div` with the class `audience-score meter` then `soup.find('div', class_ = 'audience-score meter')` will return `None` . Any subsequent `find` or `contents` on this will result in an `AttributeError`

A solution would be to try-except this and set the value to empty string.

```
try:    
    audience_score = soup.find('div', class_ = 'audience-score meter').find('span').contents[0][:-1]
except AttributeError:
    audience_score=""
```

Do the same for `title` and `num_audience_ratings`(both assignments)

Comment: Goo suggestion for the troubleshooting. Still not sure why it's happening, I found the tags to be identical to the other files in the loop. This will work to get past it for now though, thanks.